# Detect if a names field exists in a record set

Tags: asp-classic

Is it possible to check if a named field is within a record set?

EG id, field1, field2, field3 have been selected.  Is it possible for VBScript to detect if field2 has been selected.  I am also hoping this is possible without looping

Please assume I dont know, nor can see the actual SELECT.  I need to detect this after the query has been executed.

This is how its done using a loop, I am also hoping this is possible without looping:

```
dim rs,field,foundField
sql = "SELECT * from table;"
set rs = conn.execute(sql)
For Each field in rs.Fields
   if field.Name = "someFieldName" then 
      foundField = true 
  exit for
   else 
      foundField = false
   end if
next
```

TYIA

Comment: Just to confirm a SELECT statement is executed on backend and the data is returned into ADO Recordset?

Comment: I'm not sure if "Collections" like Fields expose a method for that, but you can always build your own function. Also note that your code will fail unless the field you're looking for is the last one (remove that else to fix it)

Comment: I have added the exit for as @bfavaretto pointed out it was never going to work unless the field that was being searched for was the last field.  Yes its an ADO RS.  I dont hink it can be done without looping but would like to know f it can?

Answer (score 10):

I use a similar function (in VB6) to the one proposed by bfavaretto... I'm curious why the OP says it doesn't work?

```
Public Function FieldExists(ByVal rs As Recordset, ByVal fieldName As String) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo merr

    FieldExists = rs.Fields(fieldName).name <> ""
    Exit Function

merr:
    FieldExists = False

End Function
```

This function works for me... and it doesn't return false negatives as far as I know. Also, it appears to be faster than executing a loop for fields that are included in the collection; for fields that are actually missing, the execution times of both methods seems to be equivalent.

---

**EDIT**

For `VBScript`, the above function would look like this:

```
Function FieldExists(ByVal rs, ByVal fieldName) 

    On Error Resume Next
    FieldExists = rs.Fields(fieldName).name <> ""
    If Err <> 0 Then FieldExists = False
    Err.Clear

End Function
```

And the code posted in the question would look like:

```
dim rs,field,foundField
sql = "SELECT * from table;"
set rs = conn.execute(sql)
foundField = FieldExists(rs, "someFieldName")
```

Comment: thank you for your input.  I and other colleagues R&D'ed this to death.  Our conclusion is that its just not possible in the Classic ASP world to identify an individual field (as described in the initial post) unless its the first one in the collection without a loop. Back when this objective was on my to do list it was also posted on other forums.  Its not just our conclusion, it was everybody's.   You have posted a function which looks like it needs to be called from a loop to be honest?

Comment: I see... For the sake of correctness, however, I'm editing my answer since I've been doing a lot of VB6 lately, and my brain decided to ignore the part where you explicitly mention that you need this to work in VBScript... The function I originaly posted won't even "compile" in VBScript.

Comment: This works great. Catch the error if the field isn't there.

Comment: @Mat41 Not true and this code proves it clever solution! It doesn't use a loop just checks for the existence by catching the error when it doesn't exist. So you and colleagues are wrong I'm afraid however much you protest. Should be the accepted answer!

Comment: You are missing the `On Error GoTo 0` in the function. I believe the `On Error Resume Next` stays on, which you usually wouldn't want.

Comment: The `On Error GoTo 0` isn't necessary in this case because the function ends immediately after validating `Err`. `On Error...` clauses only stay on within the function/sub they were invoked from.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the loop. Found this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525228%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Most of the ASP built-in objects provide collections. Collections are
>   data structures similar to arrays that store strings, numbers, objects
>   and other values. Unlike arrays, collections expand and contract
>   automatically as items are retrieved or stored. The position of an
>   item will also move as the collection is modified. **You can access an
>   item in a collection by its unique string key, by its index (position)
>   in the collection, or by iterating through all the items in the
>   collection.**

In any case, you could try this (untested):

```vb
dim rs,field,foundField
sql = "SELECT * from table;"
set rs = conn.execute(sql)
if rs.Fields("someFieldName") then
    ' ... if this doesn't crash, it may return
    ' false negatives for columns containing null or 0 
end if
```

Comment: Tanks for you info but no that doesnt work.  It appears like the loop is required.